# Custom setting deployment

Tags: apex, deployment, metadata-api, customsetting

I have a custom setting called CAT_Custom into which i have a URL field called CAT_URL. I have different values for this URL field in both PROD and in STAGE environments.

Now when i deploy this custom setting from stage to prod, will the URL value in prod get replaced by the value in stage or will it not be overridden?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom settings act like sObjects and therefore the fields Values you're talking about are just like any other record of any other Object, since on the change sets you're only deploying metadata, there's no records there, so the values of instances of Custom settings will not be populated by any deploy.